# Direct Spring DEBUG logging to Console

Tags: spring, slf4j, log4j2

I have a Maven project and I want to direct DEBUG Spring logging to the console.

My log interface is slf4j and I'm binding to Log4j2.

In my pom.xml I have excluded commons-logging in favour or Slf4j:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
      <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I believe slf4j is wired up correctly because I have this in my log4j2.xml:

```
<Logger name="com.myApp" level="info" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
</Logger>
```

This in my test class constructor:

```
logger.info("constructor");
logger.debug("constructor");
```

and if i flip the log level in log4j2.xml from info/debug I get one or two log lines in the console.

I also have this in my log4j2.xml:

```
   <Logger name="org.springframework" level="all" additivity="false">
       <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
   </Logger>
```

But it has zero effect. What am I missing? Why doesn't Spring log detailed debug lines to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Found it if it helps anyone else. This dependency was missing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

So logging looks like its working, but Spring logging is not.